# DRY Principles for FastAPI + Jinja2 Web App (Front and Backend)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, dry, fastapi

I'm learning FastAPI by building a basic Blog. I finished the schema, CRUD, and API and I'm trying to implement a frontend with Jinja2 templates. However, as soon as I started writing the webapp front end I realized I'm literally re-writing every single "back-end" API function for the frontend. This can't possibly be correct.

For example, in order to render a html blog feed on the front end (app/webapp/article/article.py), it seems like I need to write identical functions to my app/api/api_v1/endpoints/article.py.

My API request to display all blog posts looks like this:

```
# DisplayArticles is a pydantic class

@router.get("/articles", response_model=DisplayArticles, tags=["articles"])
async def get_articles(
        tag: str = "",
        db: AsyncIOMotorClient = Depends(get_database),
):
    filters = ArticleFilters(
        tag=tag
    )
    dbarticles = await get_articles_with_filters(
        db, filters
    )
    return create_aliased_response(
        DisplayArticles(articles=dbarticles, articles_count=len(dbarticles))
    )
```

And then I found myself essentially rewriting an identical function for my webapp, except I replaced the return statement with `return templates.TemplateResponse` and added a bit of context metadata.

My goal was to design a project structure that would allow the project to easily grow/scale whiteout needing to be restructured.

Here is a skeleton of my slightly simplified file structure:

```
app/

-api/

--api_v1/

---api/

---api.py       # holds the `router.include_router(router_name)` from endpoints/*

----endpoints/

-----article.py     # holds routes returning pydantic response models

-----tag.py

-core/

--config.py

--utils.py

-crud/

--article.py     # all the usual CRUD type methods with DB filters etc

--tag.py

-db/

--database.py

-models/

--article.py     # pydantic models

--tag.py

-templates/     # Jinja2 templates

--assets/

--base.html

-webapp/ 

--articles/

--base.py

-main.py
```

Comment: This might be a better fit for Code Review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) or Software Engineering (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You can move `get_articles_with_filters` to a dependency instead, and then use `articles = Depends(get_articles_with_filters)` in your view definitions, re-using the functionality across both routes